# microtype settings for Adobe Caslon Pro?

Tags: fonts, microtype

Has anyone developed `microtype` settings for Adobe Caslon Pro? After a lot of searching, I cannot find a definitive upstream source for the `microtype` package, and the latest version I can find (2.5 beta 8) seems not to have settings for Adobe Caslon Pro, hence I was wondering if anyone had developed them independently (again, searching online didn't come up with anything).

Comment: If nobody can provide a customized set for `Adobe Caslon Pro`, you could try adapting the settings developed for `Palatino`. If nothing else, the settings for `Palatino` should give you a good starting point.

Comment: The `microtype` package gained support for external OpenType/TT fonts only relatively recently (with XeLaTeX), hence, there are not many sources of custom settings for protrusion etc. The same situation applies to Minion Pro, which uses the default settings (protrusion 50%, IIRC).

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently using Adobe Caslon Pro in my document alongside micro type. These are the settings I have:

```
\usepackage[
  activate={true,nocompatibility},
  final,
  tracking=true,
  factor=1200,
  stretch=50,
  shrink=0
  ]{microtype}
```

These settings look great for me and so far these are the parameters I've been successfully able to tinker with. Be sure to use the beta of micro type (2.5 build8) to prevent any issues with xetex or luatex.

I'm building my documents via LuaLaTeX and I'm using `microtype` 2.5 beta 8. So far everything works fine.

Comment: Where can I get the beta 8? I've got beta 7 using `sudo  tlmgr --repository http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2012 update microtype`.

Comment: @ NVaughan here, try this link: http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/cgi-bin/package.cgi/action=view/id=569

Comment: Cheers, gracias!

Comment: The activate option looks useful. Some things I don't understand about the above: first, you specify tracking=true, but then you don't use tracking. Next, you specify factor=1200, but you don't specify a font size, so it's hard to judge whether it's a good idea; ditto for stretch and shrink. I can't see a reason to pass "final" when there's no "draft" for it to override. I'm really after glyph-by-glyph adjustments for Caslon, as is supplied for some fonts in the package, e.g. Times.

Comment: @ReubenThomas I'm working on a comprehensive microtype configuration file for caslon pro, as I'm sure that's what you really want, but it will take time to do it right. Meantime, I decided to post the above for people to adjust to their liking.

Comment: Great, I look forward to that. As I said, I can't actually tell what most of the basic settings above are intended to do, because of missing context, and I explained why in each case.