# Microtype configuration for kpfonts

Tags: microtype, kpfonts

The `microtype` documentation suggests to use settings matching one's font choice. I am currently using the `kpfonts` package but have not succeeded to find some matching settings online.

As there seem to be people on this site who are able to produce microtype configuration for new fonts ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97193/microtype-package-with-libertine-font), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/microtype-settings-for-adobe-caslon-pro)) I would kindly ask for someone to provide matching `microtype` settings for `kpfonts`.

Comment: I would also highly appreciate this, especially if it gives the implementer an opportunity to explain some fine details and whether there are any peculiarities inherent in kpfonts that make this easy or hard.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example which illustrates some of the places where the generic settings seem to do badly?

Comment: @cfr That's part of the problem: I'm no typography expert (in fact I do use LaTeX because it takes care of those things) and would probably not notice any "bad case".

Comment: @cfr I noticed some posts, from 2012, indicating that protrusion was font specific.  Is that not true today? Or has the issue been otherwise handled. I really love the idea of microtype, but like DavidWoitkowski, I'm far from an expert typographer. Other than `\usepackage{microtype}' I have not idea what the "generic settings" might be.

Comment: @AFeldman Ideally, the settings are font-specific because they should be tailored to the specific features of that font. If `microtype` can't find font-specific settings, it applies some generic defaults. These are described in the documentation, but tend to be fairly conservative because that's the only thing which makes sense for the default case. The same with `microtype`'s other features. Settings also depend on the engine in some cases because only pdfTeX supports the full set of features.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: I suggest to close this question after three years without any answer. Fortunately even for pdfLaTeX more and more fonts become available and nobody provides individual cfg files for microtype. Besides this it is unclear, what the OP expects from such a cfg file. I use microtype in every and each document with various fonts and except for palatino sans I never ever noticed botched typesetting because of microtype.