# Microtype settings for Adobe Caslon Pro (LuaLaTeX)

Tags: fonts, luatex, typography, microtype

---

This is a follow-up question for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/microtype-settings-for-adobe-caslon-pro)

---

Hello, I'm trying to use *Adobe Caslon Pro* font, which I have installed on my machine. This is an Open Type Font.

In the aforementioned question (which I think is kind of outdated being it from 2012), some gudielines are provided, and then discussed, It refers to an old version of the `microtype` package, and of course an old Lua/XeLaTeX version.

Since I'm using TeX Live 2016, I'd like to know how I can possibly set the `microtype` options to obtain a good typographical solution with the packages and engine as they are today.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `microtype` package ships with configurations files for some fonts.  These are located in the directory where `microtype` is installed (for TeXlive in the standard location on GNU/Linux this is `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype`), but you can also obtain [this directory from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/microtype.tds.zip).

You can use one of these files to come up with your handcrafted protrusion values for Adobe Caslon.  Some are quite extensive, for example `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg`, because this maps out a lot of Unicode glyphs to have nice kerning around things like `℃`.